# Keras, training with an empty category

Tags: tensorflow, keras, categorical-data

Maybe it is a naive question.
I want to try a small experiment for research: train the model with an extra and empty category from the one that I have in the training and validation and see how the prediction for this extra category goes down with the number of samples and epochs.
In particular I added a 5th phantom category in the pandas dataframe.
I am also using an ImageDataGenerator.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=0,
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.0,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=False,
    width_shift_range=0.0,
    height_shift_range=0.0
)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    train_df, 
    "/mypath/", 
    x_col='filename',
    y_col='category',
    target_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=batch_size
)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    validate_df, 
    "/mypath/", 
    x_col='filename',
    y_col='category',
    target_size=IMAGE_SIZE,
    class_mode='categorical',
    batch_size=batch_size
)

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator, 
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=total_validate//batch_size,
    steps_per_epoch=total_train//batch_size,
    callbacks=callbacks
)
```

However when I a try to train the CNN I got the following error:

```
Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (5,) but got array with shape (4,)
```

Someone can suggest a workaround?

Comment: You also need to update the model output to have shape (5,)

Comment: Actually is the opposite. I already made the model to have as output shape 5. I need to shape the input to have shape 5.